# How can I get CISA weekly summary sorted by vendor rather than by CVE?

Tags: vulnerability, cve

I subscribe to the CISA's weekly vulnerability summary email.

This USED to come sorted by vendor/product, so I could quickly skip over the Cisco and Wordpress vulnerabilities to check the stuff I care about.

But some months ago they started sorting by CVE number, which is pretty useless for my purposes. Viewing the report on the CISA website has the same order.

Does anyone know of a way to get these reports sorted by vendor/product?

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem here: I want the list of vendors/products, and then for each of these their list of CVE. I used to save the HTML code of the web page, and then use some grep / sed / awk / text editor formating etc Linux hacks.

But it seem the code change a bit more or less every week. So I switched to IA (Bard) to do some webscraping in Python. I expect it to be broken on a regular basis, but one of the major quality of IA is its infinite patience to do, re-do, and re-re-do things endlessly a task with some adjustment if needed.

This being said, CISA could publish its weekly report in JSON alongside the web page: this would simplify the work of a lot of people.